# Xcode 14.1 - simulator constantly gets frozen while launching the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator

I am using **Xcode 14.1**, MacOS 13.2.1, and running different simulators(**iPhone 14 Pro 16.1** etc.), and every 2-4 times I rerun the app the simulator gets frozen. Xcode says **Launching...** but the simulator shows a black screen. Waiting does not help. So I constantly need to shut the simulator down which is really annoying.

Is there a way to fix it or is it currently a "normal" behavior?

Comment: Please find the possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665691/8751294

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816206/165324

Answer (score 0):

I also facing same issue for specific app not all apps.

1. Force Quit Simulator.
2. Run Again

**My Work around.**

I stop app by clicking (x) from simulator and not from Xcode.

[image]

Comment: yes, that is what I am doing. Force quitting simulator by CMD+Q. And in 2-4 runs I have the same issue and need to force quit again